# Relay output current confused?

Tags: relay

Relays have output different ratings on their case.

Just For eg..output DC 100v 25 amp, 60 volt  45 amps.

Now, I would like to output 25 to 30 amps under 12v voltage DC supply.  Since the rating  (voltage and power)) is within the specified above intervals, any harm in supplying the relay with 12v DC to output 30 amps.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [relay ratings at 120v and 240v...can I use a 20A 240V relay with a 13A 120V pump?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196976/relay-ratings-at-120v-and-240v-can-i-use-a-20a-240v-relay-with-a-13a-120v-pump)

Answer (score 0):

The *output* ratings are maximum values. So you can use the 45A's relay in the 25-30A application.

Note, that the *input* voltage and current has a minimum value too, to be able to switch the relay.